# Kotlin reified issue with parameterized type

Tags: kotlin, jackson

Why does the following not work? 
It seems that the type Foo is not passed properly, or is this just a well known "issue"?

`Foo<T>` fails

```kotlin
data class Foo<T>(val a: T)
data class Bar(val b: String)
val objectMapper = ObjectMapper().registerKotlinModule()
val jsonString = "{\"a\": { \"b\": \"str\" }}"
fun main() {
    val parseJson = parseJson<Bar>()
}
private inline fun <reified T> parseJson(): T {
    val readValue: Foo<T> = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString)
    return readValue.a
}
```

```
class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class ..Bar 
(java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; 
..Bar is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in this case is that you're not specifying the class that ObjectMapper should try and map your `jsonString` to. The matter is further complicated by the `Foo` type being parametric.

You need to build a `JavaType` reference to pass to `objectMapper.readValue`.

```kotlin
private inline fun <reified T> parseJson(): T {
    val javaType = objectMapper.typeFactory.constructParametricType(Foo::class.java, T::class.java)
    val readValue: Foo<T> = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, javaType)
    return readValue.a
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is this a good solution performance wise? I saw that this do cache simple types, but not this case. Should I cache the JavaTypw myself?

Comment: @J2B I'd suggest you to have a look at kotlinx.serialization instead for performance as it does not use reflection to serialize/deserialize json.